# Excel count total number of cells that contain x on all sheets without specifying sheet names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbook with 50+ sheets that have the same layout but have different items on them and one sheet that is used as a master sheet with every item on it. Im wanting to count the number of each times the item is found across every sheet in the workbook.

Something like this but count every sheet in the workbook without specifying each sheet name.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2,Sheet2!D:D&Sheet3!D:D&Sheet4!D:D))))
```

Example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try this. It's a worksheet function that you can call in the master sheet like =CountAcrossWorksheets(a2, column($D1).

Note that it is totally non-volatile, so you will need to add a few lines if you want this to re-calculate every time you add stuff to column D. If you don't like indexing over the whole column, you can also add some stuff to only check through the second row to the last occupied row.

```
Function CountAcrossWorksheets(itemToLookFor As Range, colIndexToCheck As Integer)    

Dim countOfItemToLookFor
    countOfItemToLookFor = 0

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    countOfItemToLookFor = countOfItemToLookFor + _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range(ConvertToLetter(colIndexToCheck) & ":" & ConvertToLetter(colIndexToCheck)), itemToLookFor)
Next

CountAcrossWorksheets = countOfItemToLookFor

End Function

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String

Dim iAlpha As Integer
Dim iRemainder As Integer

    iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
    iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)

If iAlpha > 0 Then

    ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)

End If

If iRemainder > 0 Then

    ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sheetnames are in a following order, you can use something like:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW(2:50)&"!D:D"),A2),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Use the "Evaluate Formula"-tool to see how it works (and then expand it as you need it)